# MySQL Convert/Cast Varchar data(stored value is currency) to Integer/Decimal not working when running SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, type-conversion

As I mentioned in Question title, in one select query, I must CAST/CONVERT a VARCHAR column to INTEGER or DECIMAL format in the query result, but not actually changing in DB Table.

I know that we can use `CAST`/`CONVERT` function for doing that but when I run this query into the table it returns 0 instead of converted value:

```
SELECT CAST("$5000" AS UNSIGNED INTEGER);
```

OR

```
SELECT CAST("$5,000" AS UNSIGNED INTEGER);
```

It should return the integer value 5000.

What could be the reason for this ? And how to achieve what I want using only MySQL query ?

Comment: You can't cast a string beginning with `$` to a number.

Comment: You also can't cast a number containing `,`.

Comment: `CAST()` extracts the longest prefix of the string containing digits and converts that to a number.

Comment: Then how can I strip these characters as and when they occur in the VARCHAR column value dynamically and then convert remaining string numbers to integers in single query ?

Comment: In MySQL 8.x you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` to remove all non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 3):

You have to clean up the string to make it a number.

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE("$5,000","$",""),",","") AS UNSIGNED INTEGER);
```

Comment: Nice effort, it works, but can I use `REGEXP` instead of using `REPLACE` multiple times, to make this conversion in one go ?

Comment: Yes, you could use REGEXP instead of REPLACE but I'm not sure why you'd want to. You'd still need to chain them as Tim has shown and the regular expression syntax is unnecessary since you are editing out literals.

Comment: Well, you're talking about "optimizing the number of keystrokes", and that's rarely a good reason for making things complicated when the simple answer works and is clear.